# How do I know if a SSL certificate is set for a wildcard

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl, system-administration

I have been gifted the responsibility of installing and managing a few SSL certificates.

Unfortunately the previous persons/company that set this up is no longer available for contact.

When I run: `openssl x509 -in /path/to/cert.crt -text -noout`

I am given a slew of information, on of them is the CN name. 
The CN name does not have an asterisk before it... its just CN=domain.com

How do I determine if this is a wildcard certificate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wildcard certificates by definition have an asterisk in either the common name or a subject alternative name field (an x509 extension that is optionally present in issued certificates). If you don't see an asterisk it's not a wildcard.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer, is very very helpful